# Parallel Task In C#.net

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I have C#.net application.
I wanted to run my application In Thread.
But because of third party dll it dont allow to use application in multiThread.
There is one object in  thrid party dll ,which only allow to create instance at one time only.

When i manually run application exe instnace multiple time & process my data it process successfully..(might because of each exe run with its application domain)

Same thing i require to implement from C# code. for that i have created dll which can accessible by Type.GetTypeFromProgID()..but multiple dll instnace creating same problem.

Is there any way i could achive manual parallelism through code to process same exe code in multiple application domain?

Comment: Is the dll a managed or unmanaged dll?